# POWER BI Calculate repeated customer?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to label each customer as a repeated one or not. A repeated customer would be a customer that placed an order on two different dates.

You'll find attached the model and the DAX formula that I'm currently using, which is not working.

The highlighted CALCULATE clause always returns the same number for every row (the total number of distinct order dates which is 1277), not taking into account the Customer ID.

Thus, every customer is concidered as a repeated one since the IF clause always returns YES (1277 > 0).

Please can someone help me solve this? I'd really appreciate.

Thank you for your time.

[image: model]
[image: DAX code]

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to apply the filter, the filter direction to Order Date is your problem most likely. The filter does not travel "upstream".

I don't know which are the columns used on the relation from Orders to Sample-Superstore, replace [ID] with the proper columns.

Create the column in the Customer table, this is import because of the Row Context necessary to apply the filter across the model.

```
Repeat Customer = 
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT(Orders[Order Date]),
        CROSSFILTER(Orders[ID],'Sample - SuperStore'[ID],Both)
    )
```

You could also set the default Crossfilter direction of the relationship to Both and in that case you only need to do the CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(